# Generating web page into image is not working for Spatie Browsershot

Tags: php, laravel, browsershot

I am developing a web application using the Laravel framework. I need to generate the web page into pdf/ image in my application. I am using PHP browser shot spatie package for it, https://github.com/spatie/browsershot. I created a test function to generate the image using it with the following code.

```
\Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::url("https://www.google.com/")->save(public_path() . '/example.png');
```

When I run the function, I got the following error.

```
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"\/var\/www\/public\/example.png","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}}}'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory: /var/www/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ sh: 1: npm: not found sh: 1: node: not found
```

I am using Docker and Docker Compose for my project. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: it says npm and node not found, then you'll need to install those

Comment: I have them on my machine

Comment: You probably do not have NPM and Node installed in your Docker image. Try adding them in your `Dockerfile` using the installation tools for the base image (Apt, Yum, Apk, etc).

Comment: Hi can I have an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell BrowserShot to point to the installation binary of node and npm.
Modify your code this way

```
\Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot::url("https://www.google.com/")
    ->setNodeBinary('/usr/bin/node')
    ->setNpmBinary('/usr/bin/npm')
    ->save(public_path() . '/example.png');
```

Make sure to modify '/usr/bin/node' and '/usr/bin/npm' accordingly.

Comment: " Make sure to modify '/usr/bin/node' and '/usr/bin/npm' accordingly. " , which path needs to pass here??